# Unity3D - Button not triggered once?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have some issues for match the string and the `InputField.text` it's triggering multiple times after `Active` or `Dead Active Gameobject` when press Submit button(in this case is "Cek Jawaban").

this my script

```cs
public void Answer(int index)
    {
        inputPanel.SetActive(true);

        inputField.text = "";

        inputPanel.transform.Find("KunciBtn").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() =>
        {
            if (inputField.text != "")
            {
                if (inputField.text == jawaban[index])
                {
                    Debug.Log("Right");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("Wrong");

                }

                inputPanel.SetActive(false);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("jangan kosong");
            }
        });
    }
```

[![Many Buttons][1]][1]

[image]

[image]

as you can see on the console at the first that triggers once but after the second time its triggers twice. Also, my `Answer()` called on every button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are adding listeners to the onClick of the button every time Answer is called, but you are never removing them. So the second time you click the button, a second listener has been added and it will look like you have pressed the button twice.

To fix this, you either need to remove the listener after you have handled the button logic:

```
...
   else
   {
      Debug.Log("jangan kosong");
   }

inputPanel.transform.Find("KunciBtn").GetComponent<Button>().onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
```

Or add the listener on Start() so that it is set once and then remove it in either OnDisable() or OnDestroy().